# I am trying to make a div appear when i scroll down a certian amont ?

Tags: javascript, html, css

just trying to make a div appear when I scroll down with some js and html, doesnt seem to be working and im not sure why ?

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 200) {
    $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.aboutfilmandcrew').fadeOut();
  }
});



#aboutfilmandcrew {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Your code should work https://jsfiddle.net/49yyxbdv/1/

Comment: hi, yeah i can see it working in that link there but it still doesnt seem to be working with notepadd ++ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with window instead of document :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() { ... });
```

The rest of your code looks correct, but in the javascript you're selecting the div with the class filmandcrew, while your css is styling the div with the id filmandcrew.

Comment: He's right also check the way you're calling that div. I see you're using a class for the jquery, but an id with the same name for the CSS. That might be an issue too...

Comment: hi, yeah i can see it working in that link there but it still doesnt seem to be working with notepadd ++ ??